# jQuery UI Accordion height issue

Tags: height, accordion

I implemented a jQuery UI accordion with several sections. My Problem is that every section is as large as the section with the longest content. (height of all sections is set to the height of the largest content section). So there is a lot of whitespace in sections with shorter content.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to use heightStyle attribute.

```
$( function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
  });
} );
```